# Display a View on Android Window Manager

Tags: android

I created an Audio player app and set it to be my default app for opening audio files.

Now when I click an audio file from filemanager, it opens my app, or rather the activity for receiving the audio file.

But I don't want it that way, I want a custom view from my app to be displayed on the filemanager app just like the image below

[image]

The app that does this is **YT Music**. And I noticed, it's not done with the Android **WindowManager** because I disabled the **Draw over apps** on the **YT Music** app but it's still popping up the view

Can anyone give me a clue of how it's done?

**Just like I said, I have a custom view which I want to display on the filemanager when an audio file is clicked and if there's a code, it should be in Java**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, I got what I was looking for...

First, it's just a normal activity displayed like a **Dialog** box.

I created an activity (DialogBoxActivity.java) and gave it a dialog theme in the AndroidManifest.xml

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".DialogBoxActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:theme="@style/DialogBoxTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="DialogBoxTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="background">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```